# Apache reverse proxy HTTPS, the process didn't start

Tags: apache, https

I'm using Apache to reverse proxy HTTPS, but the process didn't start. The reverse proxy for HTTP starts normally. When comparing the logs, there are no error messages, and the HTTPS log stops at a certain line. I can't think of any other reasons.
The configuration is as follows:

```
<VirtualHost 10.100.209.21:7777>
    Include /nafinstance/configs/sites/88099e1e-6e71-11ee-9637-fa163e4aeea1/mod.inc
    KeepAlive On

    SetEnv proxy-nokeepalive 1
    Timeout 60
    ProxyTimeout 60

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /nafinstance/configs/sites/88099e1e-6e71-11ee-9637-fa163e4aeea1/ssl.public.key
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /nafinstance/configs/sites/88099e1e-6e71-11ee-9637-fa163e4aeea1/ssl.private.key
    
    ErrorLog "/nafinstance/proxy/Rapache/logs/10.100.209.20_9100.log"

    ProxySourceAddress 10.100.209.21

    SecSiteID 88099e1e-6e71-11ee-9637-fa163e4aeea1
    SecSensorId 63eeab7f-543d-11ee-aa5c-fa163ec70d09
    SecPolicyID 497542bc-06f6-4ee5-bcb0-444efa5a41df

    ProxyPass / http://10.100.209.20:9100/ retry=0
    ProxyPassReverse / http://10.100.209.20:9100/
    
    
</VirtualHost>
```

The log is as follows:

```
[Fri Oct 20 10:35:23.796028 2023] [unique_id:info] [pid 199187:tid 140471868985920] AH01566: using ip addr 127.0.0.1
[Fri Oct 20 10:35:24.000514 2023] [ssl:info] [pid 199187:tid 140471868985920] AH01887: Init: Initializing (virtual) servers for SSL
[Fri Oct 20 10:35:24.001154 2023] [ssl:info] [pid 199187:tid 140471868985920] AH01876: mod_ssl/2.4.26 compiled against Server: */2.4.26, Library: OpenSS
L/1.0.2l
[Fri Oct 20 10:35:24.001224 2023] [http2:debug] [pid 199187:tid 140471868985920] mod_http2.c(107): AH03089: initializing post config dry run
[Fri Oct 20 10:35:24.001235 2023] [:notice] [pid 199187:tid 140471868985920] ModSecurity for Apache/2.9.1 (http://www.modsecurity.org/) configured.
[Fri Oct 20 10:35:24.001239 2023] [:notice] [pid 199187:tid 140471868985920] ModSecurity: APR compiled version="1.5.2"; loaded version="1.5.2"
[Fri Oct 20 10:35:24.001244 2023] [:notice] [pid 199187:tid 140471868985920] ModSecurity: PCRE compiled version="8.32 "; loaded version="8.44 2020-02-12
"
[Fri Oct 20 10:35:24.001247 2023] [:warn] [pid 199187:tid 140471868985920] ModSecurity: Loaded PCRE do not match with compiled!
[Fri Oct 20 10:35:24.001249 2023] [:notice] [pid 199187:tid 140471868985920] ModSecurity: LUA compiled version="Lua 5.1"
[Fri Oct 20 10:35:24.001251 2023] [:notice] [pid 199187:tid 140471868985920] ModSecurity: YAJL compiled version="2.0.4"
[Fri Oct 20 10:35:24.001254 2023] [:notice] [pid 199187:tid 140471868985920] ModSecurity: LIBXML compiled version="2.9.1"
[Fri Oct 20 10:35:24.001256 2023] [:notice] [pid 199187:tid 140471868985920] ModSecurity: Status engine is currently disabled, enable it by set SecStatu
sEngine to On.
[Fri Oct 20 10:35:24.119214 2023] [unique_id:info] [pid 199188:tid 140471868985920] AH01566: using ip addr 127.0.0.1
[Fri Oct 20 10:35:25.001076 2023] [ssl:warn] [pid 199188:tid 140471868985920] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Fri Oct 20 10:35:25.001187 2023] [ssl:info] [pid 199188:tid 140471868985920] AH01887: Init: Initializing (virtual) servers for SSL
```

I attempted to analyze the issue through the logs, but there's no useful error information. When compared to the normal situation, the log stops at a certain line.

Comment: This is a similar issue like this one: https://serverfault.com/a/1084103. Could you check that?